# Paper Flip Jquery & CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, page-flipping

Is there a method to make Paper flipping using javascript, Jquery & || or CSS ?

I found [this method](http://www.turnjs.com/) but it's not free.

So is there a free way to do it ?

Comment: Yes, there is: Code it. [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: Nothing, I dunno where can I start from.

Comment: Actually, turn.js [appears to be open-source](https://github.com/blasten/turn.js), or [take a look at this](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/5-free-jquery-page-flip-plugins-for-book-like-interfaces/)

Comment: Open Source ≠ free (you need to purchase a license to use turn.js for commercial projects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this tutorial has a good overview of the javascript and css used.

[Fullscreen PaperFlip](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/12/11/fullscreen-pageflip-layout/)

Answer (score 1):

you can try using [booklet](http://builtbywill.com/code/booklet/)  or [curl](https://github.com/elliottkember/the-sexy-curls-jquery-plugin)